# Override a vendor class which is not directly called - Laravel

Tags: laravel, oop

I have two classes namely `class A` and `class B` of a package. `class B` is injected into `class A`'s constructor through dependency injection.

I need to override a function in `class B`. To do this I have:

1. Cloned `class B` to a new `Class C` and changed that required function.
2. Bound the new `class C` to `class B` in service provider:

   `$this->app->bind(ClassB::class, function() use ($app){
           return $app->make(ClassC::class);
       });`

I'm now getting the error `Class A` expects instance of `class B` only.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS I am trying to implement an insert-ignore function instead of insert in laravel excel package

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to extend class B and override function you need instead of cloning?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "cloned" class B? Did you just copy and paste the code? You'll need to extend it to inject class C into class A.

Comment: I think extending will work if class B is directly used

Comment: @CalumHalpin Yes I copy pasted the class B into class C and also tried to extend class B but unfortunately most functions are of private scope plus class A only allows class B's instance.

Comment: "class A only allows class B's instance" if it does this by type hinting then it will also allow children of class B. It's the function that you are trying to override private? If not then extension will work. Don't copy the code from class B, just write the method you want to override. The rest will be inherited.